# Object Expected error, javascript, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception

I'm getting an object expected error in a javascript file. In this case does it mean that the jQuery files aren't included properly?

The line that is causing the error is...

```
$(function () {
```

The error in the browser is...

```
Message: Object expected
Line: 6
Char: 1
Code: 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible - if the files weren't included, then the `$` variable would indeed not be an object where one was expected.  "Object expected" errors usually mean that you have a variable that is `null`/`undefined` and then try to call methods on it.

I'd try to find out if this is the case with a simple `alert($);` and see whether the result is `undefined` (bad) or something else (probably good).

Comment: Great, I put the alert($) in and it wasn't null. Turned out it was to do with the scripts being included in the wrong order. Thanks for your help.